# Does Intel Pentium supports Virtualization?

Tags: haxm

On my BIOS i have option for Virtualization, but even after enabling it am not able to install HAXM. I tried unchecking hyper-V.
All my attempts failed in installing HAXM. Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm if your OS is indeed sensing that virtualization is enabled.

1. Download the Intel Processor Identification Utility for windows.
   Check it out here -> [Intel tool](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/tools/piu/)
2. Once it is installed go to, CPU technologies tab and below you will see Intel Virtulization Technology and opposite to that you will see either a Yes or No.
3. There is a tool available from Microsoft also. 
   Check it here ->
   [Microsoft tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=592)
4. If it's a no, you may wanna check bios settings again for enabling virtualization option and then try checking the status again.
5. If it's a Yes then try installing Intel HAXM. If it's still No, maybe your OS is having some problem.